# getting advapi32.dll error while installing jdk1.8 from windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, java-8

I was trying to install Java JDK 1.8 on my Windows XP but I got the error

```
The Procedure Entry Point RegDeleteKeyExA could not be located in dynamic link library ADVAPI32.dll
```

What may be the source of this issue and how can I fix it?

Comment: Advanced Windows API is an essential Windows system DLL. It might have been corrupted or you might have a bad version of it. RegDeleteKeyExA was added in NT 3.51. XP should definitely have it. You might also want to read this (but I never verified it): http://www.wnd.com/2013/06/nsa-has-total-access-via-microsoft-windows/

Comment: possible duplicate of [installing JDK8 on Windows XP - advapi32.dll error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20965564/installing-jdk8-on-windows-xp-advapi32-dll-error)

Comment: @AlexPakka as a side note: `RegDeleteKeyEx` (both A and W variants) is *not* available prior to Vista; it's `RegDeleteKey` that's available from NT 3.51 (or rather Win2K, AFAIR) - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724845%28v=vs.85%29.aspx ; http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724847%28v=vs.85%29.aspx ; http://sourceforge.net/p/poco/bugs/495/ ; http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/43cc1a76-4295-49bf-b2f9-da90dcefd82b/how-can-i-use-regdeletekeyex?forum=vcgeneral etc

Comment: @vaxquis - you seem to be right. I think the MSDN documentation source I was using contains a mistake or I misread it.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this problem can be found here : [Installing jdk8 on windows XP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20965564/installing-jdk8-on-windows-xp-advapi32-dll-error?answertab=votes#tab-top)
As of today, only the installer is not compatible with Windows XP. The JRE and the JDK are not supported but work.