# Where can I find Java 8 src.zip

Tags: java, java-8

I have just followed following link to unpack jdk 8 on XP.

[installing JDK8 on Windows XP - advapi32.dll error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20965564/installing-jdk8-on-windows-xp-advapi32-dll-error)

but I don't see any src.zip in it.

Comment: https://jdk8.java.net/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After installing src.zip is placed in /java/jdk folder.

Comment: In windows xp you have to self uncompress the exe. At least in my case i saw no src.zip

Comment: Yup. Same with me. I consider this answer the kind of "Q: where on my disk is the config for httpd? A: on your disk. use find." ... not helpful at all.

Comment: This is not necessarily true in most recent answers. If you still can't find it: Look below.

Answer (score 25):

Download the [Linux JDK .tar.gz](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8-b132/jdk-8-linux-i586.tar.gz). It contains the src.zip

Comment: Since the same happened to me, many thanks for actually *solving the problem* and for providing the info on linux JDK's src.zip, Wlofrevo.

Comment: Excellent suggestion. Be aware that the direct link posted in the answer won't work. You need to go through Oracle's download page (currently [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html), but that can change) and accept the license before the server will allow the download.