# Which Jdk version will support windows xp

Tags: java, windows, windows-xp

Which JDK version will support windows xp? I am installed android studio on windows xp service pack 2 32bit, and it asks for jdk. i am also downloaded jdk 8u5 windows i586 version. While opening the exe file i am getting an error message . This is error :

```
 The procedure entry point RegDeleteKeyExA could not be located in the dynamic link    library ADVAPI32.dll
```

Answer (score 1):

JDK 7 is supported on Windows XP.

Installer of JDK8 does not allow JDK8 to be installed on WinXP. But as far as I know there's no technical problem to run JDK8 on WinXP if [you install it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20965564/installing-jdk8-on-windows-xp-advapi32-dll-error).

Answer (score 1):

Oracle has dropped support for windows xp.

From [Oracle page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/config-417990.html)

> Note: As of April 8, 2014 Microsoft stopped supporting Windows XP and therefore it is no longer a supported platform. See Third Party Vendor-Specific Support Terms on Oracle Software Technical Support Policies for details.

Even though the java binaries are compatible the installer is not. You can either use an older java version like JDK 7 or 6 or you may try step given in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20965564/installing-jdk8-on-windows-xp-advapi32-dll-error).

You can find good step by step solution with screenshot [here](http://www.kriblog.com/j2se/general/the-procedure-entry-point-regdeletekeyexa-could-not-be-located-in-the-dynamic-link-library-advapi32.dll.html).

Comment: Thanks. Which version can i install x86 or x64?

Comment: That depends is you windows 32 bit or 64 bit? If you are not sure you can install x86 one.

Answer (score 0):

You can try JDK 6 or JDK 7.

See this note from Oracle:

`Note: As of April 8, 2014 Microsoft stopped supporting Windows XP and therefore it is no longer a supported platform. See Third Party Vendor-Specific Support Terms on Oracle Software Technical Support Policies for details`

**See also**:
[Oracle Java](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/config-417990.html)