# Installed the latest version of Android Studio, Exception occurred when I built the project?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, retrolambda

An Android project, It was good with the older version of Android Studio. But after I updated the IDE version, An exception will occured when I build the project whith gradle.

Here is the problem:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':jellyrefresh:compileReleaseJava'.
>
> > When running gradle with java 5, 6 or 7, you must set the path to jdk8, either with property retrolambda.jdk or environment variable
> >     JAVA8_HOME

The thing is, my environment is Windows XP(I don't want to update), So **I cannot install *Java 8***, so no need to tell me to do that. But I still want to use the [Android Studio's latest version](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#top).

So what's the most resonable solution to this exception?

Comment: java 7 works with latest android studio , can u mention the jdk path in android project properties?

Comment: I think [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20965564/installing-jdk8-on-windows-xp-advapi32-dll-error) would be your solution. if you couldn't use any other jdk with ADT.

Comment: I'm truely using Java7, And I already configured the jdk path in android project peoperties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can open **build.gradle** to take a look, maybe you used **retrolambda** to compile javacode, which needs java8.

Answer (score 17):

Go to **File -> Project Structure -> SDK Location -> JDK Location** and change the path to Java 8 Home, then Rebuild project.

[image]

The snapshot was taken from Mac. However, it should work for others too.

Comment: Thanks. In a project retrolambda is used, but after downloading Java 8 setting JAVA8_HOME hasn't helped. Your advise has helped.